# Editing errors in shapefile

Tags: geometry, merge, error

qgis version: 3.4.9-Madeira

I am editing a shapefile.

I want merge two adjacent polygon.

[image: selected two adjacent polygon]

Then, I run merge tool, and it comes like below picture.

[image]

You can see some gap(?) or tail shape line between two polygon.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify what GIS software you are using.

Comment: Could you please look and see if the remaining dangle in fact has a gap or multiple vertices?

Comment: Could you add the original geometries as WKT into your question?